# Haskell Binary Tree with only chars

Tags: haskell, tree, char, binary-tree, type-variables

Lets say I make my tree like this

`data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)`

But I want to make a tree that uses only chars I don't need it to be template. I know my tree will use only chars if I make it like the one above I can't make `if dataOfNode == ')'` in a function because It says that it is a [char] type and it expects [a] type.

How to make a tree that would use only chars or is there a way to make this type of check `dataOfNode == ')'` with this type of tree that I gave. Can you give me a short example of a function that let's say check if the data in this node is the sign ')' ?

Edit:
 As requested I am posting the function that I would like to make   `

```
buildTreeHelper :: (Ord a) => String -> a -> Int -> String -> Tree a -> Tree a
buildTreeHelper str blank turn path t
 | str == [] = t
 | front == '(' = buildTreeHelper (tail str) blank 1 ('L':path) (expandTree (reverse path) blank t)
 | front == ')' = buildTreeHelper (tail str) blank 2 (tail path) t
 | turn == 1 = buildTreeHelper (tail str) blank 2 (tail path) (expandTree (reverse path) front t)
 | turn == 2 = buildTreeHelper (tail str) blank 3 ('R':path) (expandTree (reverse path) front t)
 | turn == 3 = buildTreeHelper (tail str) blank 2 (tail path) (expandTree (reverse path) front t)
 where 
  front = head str
```

Logically it is not finished but also I can't use it because it takes a string which I divade char by char. That's why I am sure I want to make my Tree only from chars so I can replace `type a` with `type char` at the begining of the function. It has other mistakes too but I think the main idea is clear.

Comment: Include the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Ok I will edit it in 2 mins.

Comment: `templates` tag along with `haskell` could lead to misunderstanding. Replacing it with `type-variables`

Comment: You don't include the definition of `expandTree`, so it's not possible to be sure, but I notice that you sometimes call `expandTree` with an argument of `blank` (which is a caller-specified type) and sometimes call it with an argument of `front` (which is a `Char`). These are not obviously the same type, and is probably the source of GHC's complaint.

Comment: Yes you are right. I made it like this because I wanted to be clearer where the problem is. Blank is also a constant char and It can't be anything else so I changed it too to 'char' type and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You easily could replace your type definition with

```
data Tree = EmptyTree | Node Char Tree Tree deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

or specialise just your function defining it as

```
buildTreeHelper :: String -> Char -> Int -> String -> Tree Char -> Tree Char
```